# scaling to a condition

Tags: probability, scales

I have some probability values which are all between 0.5 and 1. Is it possible for me to scale these values between 0 and 1 with the top 7% between 0.5 and 1 only being above 0.5 in the new scale?

Comment: You could do almost anything you want but what is your motivation and what would be the statistical justification?

Comment: I have a justification based on the domain the data is coming from. Please could you tell me how to do this?